# Is it possible to create some sort of filtration in leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

I was trying to look for some sort of filtration system anywhere, that could allow the user to show/hide streets or any other information being displayed in the map. 
Something like in this image below showing/hiding the waterlines:[image]

It would use some tags or some sort of checkboxes to toggle the display of it. Does anyone have any idea if this is possible to be done and how to do it?

Comment: If all of the informations are displayed on the tileSet, then you will need another tileSet without this information to use when you will apply your filters

Comment: @Aesahaettr I've been trying to find a way to do this, but I don't see anyone talking about it, do you have any idea on how I could do it?

Comment: I don't have an answer, what you are asking seem complex. But you could try to find first all the tileSets that meet your criteria, then by using checkbox and radiobutton change the tileSet depending on the choice made by the user. Check [this](https://www.jawg.io/docs/integration/leaflet/change-style/), it provides an example on how to change tileSet